# V.S. code terminal not refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-code

today while I was working with some code, I noticed that my terminal wasn't refreshing on VS Code when I ran the code on the terminal. For example, running this code in terminal

```
from spellchecker import spellchecker


def get_file():
    SP = spellchecker("english_words.txt")
    while True:
        try:
            fname = input('Enter the name of the file to read:')
            text = open(fname, 'r')
        except:
            print('ha')
print('Welcome to the Text File Spellchecker.')
get_file()
```

and then inputting *asd* should print 'ha' because *asd* isn't an actual file. I was testing things, and tried deleting "**except:**" and here's my new code that I ran through terminal.

```
from spellchecker import spellchecker


def get_file():
    SP = spellchecker("english_words.txt")
    while True:
        try:
            fname = input('Enter the name of the file to read:')
            text = open(fname, 'r')
print('Welcome to the Text File Spellchecker.')
get_file()
```

doing this should give me an index error but instead, it outputs the same output that I received with the first code that had the **except:** in it.

Anyone know why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

spellchecker is a class this means you have to write:

```
from spellchecker import Spellchecker
```